ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 5 is different from 3)
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
from scipy.linalg import pinv

# Define necessary functions
def create_laplacian_from_adjacency(adj_matrix):
    degree_matrix = np.diag(adj_matrix.sum(axis=1))

    laplacian_matrix = degree_matrix - adj_matrix
    
    return laplacian_matrix

def dirichlet_energy(L, X):
    """Dirichlet energy for smoothness quantification."""
    return np.trace(X.T @ L @ X)

def update_C(X, X_tilde, L, C, gamma, alpha, lam, J):
    """Updating C using gradient descent with a majorized function approximation."""
    p, k = C.shape
    C_old = np.copy(C)
    
    gradient_f = (-2 * gamma * L @ C_old @ inv(C_old.T @ L @ C_old + J) +
                  alpha * (C_old @ X_tilde - X) @ X_tilde.T +
                  2 * L @ C_old @ X_tilde @ X_tilde.T + lam * C_old @ np.ones((k, k)))
    
    # Majorized function optimization step (simplified approach)
    t = 0.01  # Learning rate, needs tuning based on actual application
    C_new = pinv(C_old - t * gradient_f)
    C_new = np.maximum(C_new, 0)  # Enforce non-negativity
    return C_new

def update_X(X, L, C, alpha):
    """Update X(tilda) based on the updated C."""
    inv_matrix = inv((2/alpha) * (C.T @ L @ C)) + (C.T @ C)
    X_tilde_new = inv_matrix @ C.T @ X
    return X_tilde_new

def fgc_algorithm(X, L, alpha, gamma, lam, iterations=5):
    """Perform the Featured Graph Coarsening algorithm."""
    p, n = X.shape
    k = 3  # Assume a reduced dimension of 3 for coarsening
    C = np.random.rand(p, k)*0.1
    J = np.full((k, k), 1/k)
    X_tilde = pinv(C)@X

    for i in range(iterations):
        C = update_C(X, X_tilde, L, C, gamma, alpha, lam, J)
        X_tilde = update_X(X, L, C, alpha)
        current_energy = dirichlet_energy(L, X_tilde)
        print(f"Iteration {i}: Dirichlet Energy = {current_energy}")

    L_c = C.T @ L @ C
    return C, L_c, X_tilde

# Example:
X = np.random.rand(5, 7)  # Random features for 10 nodes
adj_matrix = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
])
L = create_laplacian_from_adjacency(adj_matrix)  # Create a sample Laplacian matrix
alpha, gamma, lam = 0.1, 1, 0.5  # Regularization parameters

C, L_c, X_tilde = fgc_algorithm(X, L, alpha, gamma, lam)
print("Updated C matrix:\n", C)
print("The L_C matrix:\n", L_c)
print("Updated feature matrix X(tilda):\n", X_tilde)


I am trying to implement the Featured Coarsened Graph Algorithm but everytime the code reaches line 34: inv_matrix = inv((2/alpha) * (C.T @ L @ C)) + (C.T @ C),
the mentioned error is raised.
I have tried checking everyting but according to me the dimensions of the matrices are correct, so I dont really understand why there is this problem?
If you happen to understand this please help.

show the shape of the three @ args.  It's hard to tell from a quick read of the code.

What's the shape of C and L?

Shape of C is (5,3) and L is (5,5)

I'm not that familiar with the algorithm, but the problem is in update_C(...) as it alters the dimensions of C from (5,3) to (3,5) on this row:
C = update_C(X, X_tilde, L, C, gamma, alpha, lam, J)

To be more precise, when doing C_new = pinv(C_old - t * gradient_f), the inverse, by definition, will have switched dimensions.
One guess is that you might miss a transpose in update_C(...). I have not studied it in detail, but assuming that you are trying to update C with eq.13 from this paper, it seems like the transpose of C should be used both in the inverse and in the gradient calculation.

